# How to solve MINLP in matlab and MOSEK?

Tags: optimization, matlab, mixed-integer-programming

I am new to MOSEK and was wondering if it is able to solve mixed integer non linear problems .

For example I need to solve this problem formulation in matlab and using MOSEK:

[The problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSKT3.png)
Any help or comment is really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/help/gads/mixed-integer-optimization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to slightly alter your problem before MOSEK can solve it. You have strict inequalities like $1<x_D$, which make no sense in numerical optimization. Either change this to $1 \leq x_D$ or to $1.00\cdots 001 \leq x_D$ (although if you add more than 12 zeros, the two constraints are numerically equivalent).

To feed your problem to MOSEK, you want to use [YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/), since MOSEK's [interface for conic optimization](http://docs.mosek.com/7.0/toolbox/A_guided_tour.html#CH:MATLAB:SEC:GUIDEDTOUR:CONIC) has a steep learning curve.